# Difference bw configmap and downwardapi

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am new to kubernetes can somebody please explain why there are multiple volume types like

- configMap
- emptyDir
- projected
- secret
- downwardAPI
- persistentVolumeClaim

For few I am able to figure out, like why we need secret instead of configmap.
For rest I am not able to understand the need for others.

Comment: Your question is very wide and is perfectly explained here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/ Please ask more particular question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is too generic to answer, here are the few comments off the top of my head

If the deployed **pod or containers** wants to have configuration data then you need to use **configMap resource**, if there are secrets or passwords its obvious to use **secret resource**.

Now if the deployed pods wants to use POD_NAME which is generated during schedule or Run time, then it need to use **DownwardAPI resources**.

Emptydir share the lifecycle with the **Deployed pod**, If the pods dies then all of the data which are stored using emptydir resource will be gone, now If you want to persist the data then you need to use **persistentVolume, persistentVolumeClaim and storageclass Resources**.

for further information [k8s volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/)

Answer (score 0):

Configmap is used to make the application specific configuration data available to container at run time.

DownwardAPI is used to make kubernetes metadata ( like pod namespace, pod name, pod ip, pod lebels etc ) available to container at run time